# Extract unique values from an SQL database to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I am quite new to `python` and trying to work on a project that requires me to extract data from an `SQL(.db)` database and output this data into an excel file.

My database File has a lot of data but the structure I have managed to print is as follows

```
Run ID | Environment

1           52

2           52

3           52

4           52

5           72

6           72

7           72

8           72
....
```

now I need to be able to output these values to an excel spreadsheet like this,

> 52|72|92|112|132

Below is my current code and it allows me to output

> 52|52|52|52|72|72|72|72

a is the `c.fetchall()` from the module access database
Any help is appreciated

```
Access_Database_Module.Access_Database(DB)    
x = 2
DBcommand = "SELECT * FROM " + a[x][0]
print(a[x][0]) 
c.execute(DBcommand)
y = c.fetchall()    

x = y

workbook = xls.Workbook('Environment.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Environment Direction')

rowNum = 0 
colNum = 1

workbook = xls.Workbook('Environment.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Environment Direction')

for item in y:
    while colNum == colNum + 1 :
        colNum 
    worksheet.write(rowNum, colNum, item[14])
    colNum += 1 

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Most databases can write a query directly to a CSV file, which can be imported into Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your query as  follows:

DBcommand = "SELECT distinct [Environment]  FROM " + a[x][0]

This will return unique values  which is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove duplicates from your database column and store it in a excel? If it so, then the below code may help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# get DB connection
con = sqlite3.connect("your DB connection")

# Read sqlite query results into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from yourDB", con)

# verify that result of SQL query is stored in the dataframe
print(df.head())

con.close()

# if you want to remove duplicate based on particular column then do this
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[column_name],inplace=True)
# else do this
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# export to Excel file
df.to_excel("filename.xlsx",index=False)
```